# Is this a correct verb: Irregularizing

Tags: word-choice, verb-forms

Similar to `regularizing`, I want to use `irregularizing` however some dictionaries have no such word. Is that a correct suggestion?

Example:

> We have found that **regularizing** the patterns in 'A' is possible by minimizing 'B' while minimizing 'C' can **irregularize** the patterns in 'A'.

Comment: Not sure if it'll fit your needs...  how about [irregulate](https://www.wordnik.com/words/irregulate)?

Comment: Could you provide some context and an idea of what you intend regularizing/irregularizing to mean?

Comment: See the updated post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although [irregulate](https://www.wordnik.com/words/irregulate) could fit the given example, a quick search in [Google's n-gram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=irregulate&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cirregulate%3B%2Cc0) shows its usage as a verb is rare in recent times.

I would suggest [disrupt](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/disrupt?q=disrupt) or [distort](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/distort?q=distort) as an alternative:

> We have found that regularizing the patterns in 'A' is possible by minimizing 'B', while minimizing 'C' can **disrupt** the patterns in 'A'.

Comment: I agree with the answer and with the ever-so-needed comma.  Without the comma, you have a [garden path sentence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden_path_sentence).

Comment: See also https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=irregulate%2C+irregularize&year_start=1800&year_end=2008.  It should perhaps be noted that irregulate/irregularize are not part of standard English at this time.

Comment: *Irregulate* does seem nonstandard, but *irregularize* can be formed productively and I see no reason to suggest it's nonstandard.

Comment: @snailplane: For some reason, I feel the meaning of *"irregularise"* is closer to "make something illegal", whereas *"irregulate"* feels closer to "disrupting a regular pattern".

Comment: @Nico Since I don't think *irregulate* can be standardly produced I'm not sure what it would mean, but to me *irregularize* clearly means "to make irregular".

Answer (score 2):

It seems like regularize has a mathematical meaning like "standardize" or "normalize." Look into the these terms since "destandardize" and "denormalize" seem to be legitimate terms.